# openCV issue with .set()

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to skip to a certain frame in a .mkv file using `openCV`.

```py
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(fileName)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, 32800)

while (cap.isOpened()):

    ret, frame = cap.read()

    if ret == True:
        cv2.imshow('Frame', frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
    else:
        cap.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

With the code above I am successfully skipping to the video, but when it ends I get the following error:

> Error- [h264 @ 0000022cd9462280] mmco: unref short failure

Comment: How are you sure the problem is with the set function ? Does it work properly without it ?

Comment: that's not the first thing I would question. CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES translates into an attempt to seek in the file. if not implemented right, that can cause trouble. the H.264 decoder throwing a fit there, is a symptom of seeking having gone wrong. -- the solution is to use something other than OpenCV for reading the video, if you **must** seek. try PyAV.